# search models tagged_with OR title like  (with acts_as_taggable_on) 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm doing a search on a model using a scope.  This is being accessed by a search form with the search parameter q.  Currently I have the code below which works fine for searches on tags associated with the model.  But I would also like to search the title field.  If I add to this scope then I will get all results where there is a tag and title matching the search term.

However, I need to return results that match the company_id and category_id, and either/or matching title or tag.  I'm stuck with how to add an OR clause to this scope.

```
  def self.get_all_products(company, category = nil, subcategory = nil, q = nil)
    scope = scoped{}
    scope = scope.where "company_id = ?", company
    scope = scope.where "category_id = ?", category unless category.blank?
    scope = scope.tagged_with(q) unless q.blank?
    scope
  end
```

I'm using Rails 3.

Comment: Can you explain what you ended up doing. I'm also using acts-as-taggable-on and want the query to return results that match either the company name or any tags associated with the record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ever consider Arel?  You can do something like this

```
t = TableName.arel_table
scope = scope.where(t[:title].eq("BLAH BLAH").or(t[:tag].eq("blah blah")))
```

or else you can do

```
scope = scope.where("title = ? OR tag = ", title_value, tag_value)
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the tags are stored in a separate table and doesn't actually belong to the table that the OP wants to query.

Comment: yep, shouldn't be accepted. The question is about acts_as_taggable and this does not work… or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I don't think scopes can help you to construct an `or` condition.  You'll have to hand-write the code to buid your `where` clause instead.  Maybe something like this...

```
clause = "company_id=?"
qparams = [company]

unless category.blank?
    clause += " or category_id=?"
    qparams <= category
end

scope.where clause, *qparams
```

Comment: hmm...thought there may be a simpler way of doing it.  Thanks for your answer :)